# c++ empty pointer passed to function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void foo(int* a, int* b){
    b=a;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* a=new int(3);
    int* b=NULL;
    foo(a, b);

    printf("b=%d\n", *b);
}
```

I expect to see b=3 is printed, however, It is a SIGSEGV. I am wondering why b points to nothing even when I make it point to a in side foo()?

Comment: `foo` doesn't change your pointer. At first, because it takes copy of pointer. To change pointer you need give pointer or reference. Like this: `void foo(int* a, int*& b)`. And second, it doesn't to assign anything to `b` at all.

Comment: Also you can't get SIGSEGV since the code wouldn't even compile as such

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen [Yes, it can.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4829e51e1c3baadc)

Comment: @VermillionAzure The code was altered. Now it of course can.

Answer (score 0):

C++ copies by value. This means that you essentially copy only the value of a variable once it is passed through arguments. The `b` inside of a your function is but a copy of the `b` in main that disappears once the function ends.

If you want to operate on the actual value, you must use a reference. Use `int* &` as the type to get a "reference to a pointer to a type int". A reference preserves the state changes that occur to it inside of a function and will change the value of `b` in `main()`.

It is recommended that you NOT do this, however. It can be considered bad style to have functions modify state if you intend to define functions in a *functional* sense instead as procedural subroutines. The reason is that there is no really clear distinction about what functions change its inputs or not without having to exhort effort to manipulate the existing type system.